# Creating geodata service from version other than DEFAULT in ArcGIS for Server?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, web-service, data

This is with ArcGIS for Server and Desktop 10.1

I want to host a geodata service, but I don't want it to be from the DEFAULT version. I want it to be from an alternate version, that I can check the changes on before I post it to the DEFAULT.

I don't see any options to do this.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you publish any type of service, you publish from a specific database connection, which points to a specific version of the database.
So, create a new database connection to the specific version that you would like to publish the geodata service from, then either add the data to a mxd and publish from there, or right-click on the version database connection in ArcCatalog and publish from there.